# Extract polygon coordinates from image (map)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision, scikit-image

I have the following map:

[image]

I want to extract the polygon coordinates (pixls), I am using the following code snipt, but the inteverted labeled image is all 0's (False):

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import io, measure, morphology
from skimage.io import imsave, imread

img = io.imread('map.png', as_gray=True)
imsave("test.png", img)

img = morphology.binary_dilation(img, selem=np.ones((5,5)))

img_inverted = np.invert(img)
img_inverted_labeled = measure.label(img_inverted)

n_lbls = np.unique(img_inverted_labeled)[1:]

pols = []
for i in n_lbls:
  img_part = (img_inverted_labeled == i)
  pols.append(measure.find_contours(img_part, level=0)[0])
```

The inverted image is as follow:

[image]

I belive the probem is in the value of the selem in this line:

```
img = morphology.binary_dilation(img, selem=np.ones((5,5)))
```

Could you please advise what is the problem in this code..

**EDIT**
The unique values if the inverted image (grayscaled):

```
[235, 227, 219, 212, 204, 230, 215, 199, 207, 188, 184, 172, 176, 196, 192, 179, 223, 211, 203, 173, 191, 228, 216, 232, 200, 208, 171, 183, 175, 180, 195, 236, 221, 234, 233, 226, 220]
```

I think I need to classify these value into two categories (white/black) based on some threshold value. Could you please confirm my finding, and if it is so how can I calculate this value?

Comment: Please describe your algorithm step by step and tell exactly when it fails and what you expect instead.

Comment: You tried cv2.findContours() ?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-detect-polygons-in-an-image-using-opencv/

Comment: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes a threshold here would work. Having a look at the minimum and maximum values of the image `0.7` seems reasonable:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import io, measure, morphology
from skimage.io import imsave, imread
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = io.imread('map.png', as_gray=True)
# do thresholding
mask = img < 0.7

plt.matshow(mask, cmap='gray')

# ij coords of perimeter
coords = np.nonzero(mask)
coords
>>> (array([ 61,  61,  61, ..., 428, 428, 428]),
     array([200, 201, 202, ..., 293, 294, 295]))
```

[image: produced mask]

And if you just want the perimeter line rather than area (as it has a width) then you could do:

```
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize

fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=150)
ax.matshow(skeletonize(mask), cmap='gray')
```

[image: skeletonized]

Comment: Thanks you very much, can I use the second image from your post in another question ?

Comment: Glad to help, yes no problem. You could link the new question here too.

Comment: it's different topic, but here is it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61834901/convert-x-y-to-latitiude-and-longitude