# Convert x,y to latitiude and longitude

Tags: numpy, geolocation, latitude-longitude, pyproj

If I have a map image where:

- The latitude and longitude of the upper left corner (x=0, y=0) are known
- The width and height of the image is known
- Zoom (z-axis) is known.

Can we compute the latitude and longitude for other coordinates in the image?
For example, in the following image if I want to compute the lat/lon values for the white ploygon (where the coordinates (x,y) are known)

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean,
Do you have any other data than the 0,0?
Could you provide some background? 
For instance if you have a polygon and you find inner polygon I may suggest other approaches.

Comment: @yovelcohen I have lats and lons for the 4 corners

Comment: Ok, So you need either one of the points of the polygon to get to the rest or a condition that a point in the bound has to meet, Do you get what I mean by a condition?
It would be easier to formulate such a condition if I knew the end goal

Comment: I would calculate a pixel size as `lat/image height` and `long\image width`, multiply by the coordinates and subtract the known point to create a reference frame.

Comment: It may be easier to show if you could provide some numbers.

Comment: @PaddyHarrison I have edited the question ith some info, do you think I can achive it with this given info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So given the information and the shape of the image, ([see previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61833327/extract-polygon-coordinates-from-image-map/61834710?noredirect=1#comment109369937_61834710)):

```
import numpy as np

top_left = np.array((32.0055597, 35.9265418))
bottom_right = np.array((33.0055597, 36.9265418))

delta = bottom_right - top_left

shape = (454, 394)[::-1] # convert from ij to xy coords

pixel_sizes = delta / shape

pixel_sizes * (80, 200) + top_left
>>> array([32.20860539, 36.36707043])
```

Gives the (x, y) or (longtiude, latitude) of your given point.

This approach can be generalised given a set of points using numpy as:

```
coords * pixel_sizes + top_left # coords is (N, 2) array
```

If `coords` is a tuple of arrays it can be converted to an `(N,2)` array using `np.column_stack`.